# How to check if numerical value of a column contains alphabets via SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file in AWS S3 that is getting loaded to AWS Glue i.e. used to apply transformations on source data files from S3. It offers PySpark scripting environment. Data looks somewhat like this:

```
"ID","CNTRY_CD","SUB_ID","PRIME_KEY","DATE"    
"123","IND","25635525","11243749772","2017-10-17"    
"123","IND","25632349","112322abcd","2017-10-17"    
"123","IND","25635234","11243kjsd434","2017-10-17"    
"123","IND","25639822","1124374343","2017-10-17"
```

Expected outcome should be like this:

```
"123","IND","25632349","112322abcd","2017-10-17"    
"123","IND","25635234","11243kjsd434","2017-10-17"
```

**Here I'm working on the field by name 'PRIME_KEY' of type integer that may contain alphabets which results in bad data format.**

Now the requirement is, I need to find out whether a primary key column of type Integer contains any alphanumeric characters instead of only numeric values using SQL query. So far, I have tried few variants of regular expressions to do this like the one below, but no luck:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL AND 
CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(100)) LIKE \'%[0-9a-z0-9]%\'
```

Source script:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
# s3 output directory
output_dir = "s3://aws-glue-scripts../.."

# Data Catalog: database and table name
db_name = "sampledb"
glue_tbl_name = "sampleTable"

datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = db_name, table_name = glue_tbl_name)
datasource_df = datasource.toDF()
datasource_df.registerTempTable("sample_tbl")
invalid_primarykey_values_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sample_tbl WHERE CAST(PRIME_KEY AS STRING) RLIKE '([a-z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-z]+)'")
invalid_primarykey_values_df.show()
```

The output of this script is given below:

+---+--------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+

|ID |CNTRY_CD|SUB_ID  |PRIME_KEY   |DATE      |

+---+--------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------+

|123|IND|25635525|**[11243749772,null]**|2017-10-17|

|123|IND|25632349|**[null,112322ab..**|2017-10-17|

|123|IND|25635234|**[null,11243kjsd..**|2017-10-17|

|123|IND|25639822|**[1124374343,null]**|2017-10-17|

+--------+--------+--------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+

I have highlighted the values for the field I'm working on. It looks somewhat different than the source data.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RLIKE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE CAST(PRIME_KEY AS STRING) RLIKE '([0-9]+[a-z]+)'
```

More generic alpha numeric filter matching.

```
WHERE CAST(PRIME_KEY AS STRING) RLIKE '([a-z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-z]+)'
```

**Edit: as per comment**

Necessary imports and udfs

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val extract_pkey = udf((x: String) => x.replaceAll("null|\\]|\\[|,", "").trim)

import spark.implicits._
```

Setting up sample data for test and cleaning with UDF

```
val df = Seq(
  ("123", "IND", "25635525", "[11243749772,null]", "2017-10-17"),
  ("123", "IND", "25632349", "[null,112322abcd]", "2017-10-17"),
  ("123", "IND", "25635234", "[null,11243kjsd434]", "2017-10-17"),
  ("123", "IND", "25639822", "[1124374343,null]", "2017-10-17")
).toDF("ID", "CNTRY_CD", "SUB_ID", "PRIME_KEY", "DATE")
  .withColumn("PRIME_KEY", extract_pkey($"PRIME_KEY"))


df.registerTempTable("tbl")

spark.sql("SELECT *  FROM tbl WHERE PRIME_KEY RLIKE '([a-z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-z]+)'")
  .show(false)

+---+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|ID |CNTRY_CD|SUB_ID  |PRIME_KEY   |DATE      |
+---+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|123|IND     |25632349|112322abcd  |2017-10-17|
|123|IND     |25635234|11243kjsd434|2017-10-17|
+---+--------+--------+------------+----------+
```